# GNU LD filling unused space

Tags: linker, ld

I'm trying to understand the behaviour of the GNU linker and how sections are treated.

I'm editing the [stm32_flash.ld](https://github.com/nitsky/stm32-example/blob/master/stm32_flash.ld) file in [this stm32 project](https://github.com/nitsky/stm32-example/).

When I modify the linker script to put the following as the first section:

```
.my_test :
{
    . = ALIGN(4);
    KEEP(*(.my_test))
    LONG(0xdeadbeef);
    . = ALIGN(4);
} >FLASH
```

I can see the built binary has the `0xdeadbeef` as the first bytes, as I would expect.

```
$ od -An -tx1 -w1 -v build/program.bin | head
ef
be
ad
de
00
a0
00
20
31
5e
```

However, if I use the following as the first section:

```
.my_test :
{
        . = ALIGN(8);
        KEEP(*(.my_test))
        FILL(0xDEADBEEF)
        . = 0x8000;
} > FLASH
```

Then it looks like the linker completely skips this section:

```
$ od -An -tx1 -w1 -v build/program.bin | head
00
a0
00
20
2d
de
00
08
c1
d9
```

But I would expect the first `0x8000` bytes to be filled with `0xdeadbeef`. Why is the linker ignoring my section?

Comment: 1) This is completely unrelated to C or C++. Don't spam tags. 2) Read [ask] and follow the advice.

Comment: Please, this is a concise and reproducible problem. I didn't mean to "spam tags", they were suggested and fairly related I thought.

Answer (score 0):

Does any of your code "emit" to section `.my_test`?

With your first example, there was a command to "emit" four bytes into that section with the `LONG` command.

With your second example, there is no explicit "emit" command. `FILL` only takes effect when it knows how much to fill: nothing emitted, nothing filled.

You either need to tell your code to put some code or data into your `.my_test` section using `__attribute__((__section__(".my_test"))` , or simply edit your second example with a `LONG` again:

```
.my_test :
{
    . = ALIGN(8);
    KEEP(*(.my_test))
    FILL(0xDEADBEEF)
    . = 0x7FFC;      /* Note shorter to accommodate following LONG */
    LONG(0xBEEFDEAD) /* Deliberately reversed to demonstrate the result */
} > FLASH
```