# Filling unused space between sections with GNU LD

Tags: linker, gnu, ld

I'm linking some code for 8088 CPU (loaded at 0xF0000..0xFFFFF) with the following LD script:

```
SECTIONS
{
    .code 0x0000 : AT(0xF0000) {
        *(.rodata);
        *(.text);
    }
    .reset 0xFFF0 : AT(0xFFFF0) {
        *(.reset)
    }
}
```

No matter what I do, the space between the two resulting segments is always filled with zeroes. I managed to get this working by explicitly setting location in the first section (as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59890333/3455614)):

```
SECTIONS
{
    .code 0x0000 : AT(0xF0000) {
        *(.rodata);
        *(.text);
        FILL(0xAD);       /* Set fill byte */
        . = 0xFFF0;       /* Force fill by setting location to the start of the next section */
    }
    .reset . : AT(0xFFFF0) {
        *(.reset)
    }
}
```

However, this looks ugly since `.code` now controls where `.reset` will start. Is there a better way to achieve this?